# Execute a command line on selected files

Tags: windows, file-management, command-line

Is there a tool that will let me select multiple files via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>, then execute a command line on all of them?

For example: select files `a.mp4`, `c.avi`, and `z.mp3`, then click a button which will execute

```
custom_script.exe a.mp4 -n 4 --option "asdf"
custom_script.exe c.avi -n 4 --option "asdf"
custom_script.exe z.mp3 -n 4 --option "asdf"
```

on the command prompt.

It could be a shell extension, stand-alone program, or maybe even an alternate file manager. But it must have a GUI where I can select them one-by-one manually.

Comment: custom_script.exe *.mp4 -n 4 --option "asdf"

Comment: Use wildcards. I think that thould be good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with Windows if you don't fear the Registry (`regedit.exe`). The Registry is potentially dangerous, since it may lead to modifications of Windows that may crash your system. That said, here's how:

Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` and create the following structure:

```
SoftwareRecommendations       (type Folder)
+  (Default)                  (type REGSZ)    content: Demo for Software Recommendations
+ command                     (type Folder)
  + (Default)                 (type REGSZ)    content: <executable> %1 <arguments>
```

It should look like this:

[image: Registry Editor]

After that you should get a context menu entry which allows executing the command for each of the files:

[image: Context menu demo]

[image: After execution]